# PHP ?Nested Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array returned from Google Maps, that looks like this:

```
array(4) { 
    ["destination_addresses"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(19) "Walsall WS2 9PS, UK" 
        [1]=> string(19) "Walsall WS2 9PS, UK" 
        [2]=> string(19) "Walsall WS2 9PS, UK" 
        [3]=> string(26) "Wolverhampton WV10 0QP, UK" 
        } 
    ["origin_addresses"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> string(18) "Stone ST15 0FL, UK" 
        }   
    ["rows"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(1) { 
            ["elements"]=> array(4) { 
                [0]=> array(3) { 
                    ["distance"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "41.9 km" 
                        ["value"]=> int(41947) 
                    } 
                    ["duration"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "36 mins" 
                        ["value"]=> int(2134) 
                    } 
                    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" 
                } 
                [1]=> array(3) { 
                    ["distance"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "41.9 km" 
                        ["value"]=> int(41947) 
                    } 
                    ["duration"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "36 mins" 
                        ["value"]=> int(2134) 
                    }
                    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK"
                 } 
                [2]=> array(3) { 
                    ["distance"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "41.9 km" 
                        ["value"]=> int(41947)
                    } 
                    ["duration"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "36 mins" 
                        ["value"]=> int(2134) 
                    } 
                    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK"
                } 
                [3]=> array(3) { 
                    ["distance"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "40.9 km" 
                        ["value"]=> int(40924) 
                    } 
                    ["duration"]=> array(2) { 
                        ["text"]=> string(7) "41 mins" 
                        ["value"]=> int(2458) 
                    } 
                    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" 
}
```

I want to be able to run through the array, and print the destination address and the distance and time values.

This prints the destination addresses ok:

```
    $length=count($properties);
    for($a=0;$a<$length;$a++)
    {
        echo '</br>Index is ' . $a . ' | id is ' . $index[$a] . ' | destination is ' . $properties["destination_addresses"][$a] . ' | time is ';

    }
```

But I can't figure out how to print the rest. I've been banging my head against the wall all night!

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: please share `var_export($the-source-array)`, it allows volunteers to easily replicate / help you. thx

Comment: $properties[duration][text]? Probably. If you'd put strucutred data instead of one-lined, it'd be better readable.

Comment: It'd be `$properties['rows'][$a]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']; // 36 mins` after the second view.

Comment: @pavel can't wait to see what a third view might give :)

Comment: If I'm not wrong based on my assumptions from your array structure it should be 
`$properties['rows'][0]['elements'][$a]['duration']['text'];`

Comment: In future please format the information you provide so its readable. Why should we spend time helping you if you cannot be bothered to make the question readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over all these journeys and print the distance and time for each potential journey, create a foreach loop and then use the `$idx` to address the subordinate parts of the muleiple arrays

```
foreach( $destination['destination_addresses'] as $idx => $to ) {
    if ( $destination['rows'][0]['elements'][$idx]['status'] == 'OK' ) {
        echo 'Going from ' . $destination['origin_addresses'][0];
        echo ' To ' . $to;
        echo ' Distance ' . $destination['rows'][0]['elements'][$idx]['distance']['text'];
        echo ' Duration ' . $destination['rows'][0]['elements'][$idx]['duration']['text'];
    } else {
        //whatever you do if the status is not OK
    }
}
```